# regex stop at the beginning of next match in multiline text

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

> ID_FIRST
>
> After each id come one or more
>   lines with diverse text
>
> ID_SECOND
>
> The pattern repeats many times
>
> ID_THIRD
>
> That's the end but could be larger

And I just want to extract each ID_* and its text below until the next ID_.

It looks easy

```
(ID_.+)([\s\S]+)
```

I've tried several combinations of greedines and flags with but it either captures all the text until the end or it stops at ID_. I guess I'm missing something elementary

https://regex101.com/r/Ruy44M/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[\s\S]` also matches a newline so `[\s\S]+` will match until the end. You could capture in group 1 matching `ID_` followed by 1+ characters.

Then capture in group 2 using a repeating pattern that matches a newline followed by using a negative lookahead `(?!` that first checks that the line does not start with ID_:

```
(ID_.+)((?:\n(?!ID_).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(ID_.+)` Capturing group 1 - Match `ID_`, then match any char 1+ times except a newline
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\n(?!ID_).*` Match newline and assert what is directly on the right is not ID_. If that is the case, match 0+ times any char except a newline
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat that 0+ times
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HrvdFi/2)

For example:

```js
const regex = /(ID_.+)((?:\n(?!ID_).*)*)/gm;
const str = `ID_FIRST

After each id come one or more
lines with diverse text

ID_SECOND

The pattern repeats many times

ID_THIRD

That's the end but could be larger`;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log("ID: " + m[1]);
  console.log("Text: " + m[2]);
}
```